# Image formation

Tags: neurology

I have learnt that the brain provides a perception of image due to previous memory and experience. Then how does a blind person attain vision after cornea replacement?

Comment: Note: Questions of neuroscience are not off-topic on biology.SE but they are also on topic on [CognitiveScience.SE](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com). If you don't get a satisfying answer here, you may want to give a try later on on this other site.